# Every Software Crashes when trying to print

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, windows-server-2019

I shifted my windows server from HDD to SSD. I installed a network printer on a local printer port. Every time the PC is restarted, the printer registry gets corrupted ( imagined by be). Any Program takes about 20 seconds to load the printer options and till then, it behaves as it has hanged. I then uninstall the printer, reinstall the printer and it works like charm till the next restart. What might be wrong?

Edit: I found out that it has to do something with print spooler. Every time that service is restarted, the port vanishes. Since the printer has no port, it hanged all the apps. What might be the issue?

Comment: Do you have a reserved address for the printer?  If not, try that and then under configurations point the port directly to that address, then restart your spooling service.

Comment: @Arctiic I do not know what you mean by reserved address for printer. The printer is shared by another network PC. So the local port directs to say - ```\\192.168.0.x\Printer1```

Comment: Yes, and if you have address assignments set as dynamic, then DHCP lease renews and chances are `x` will change to a different address number, which tends to not play nice with network printer configurations.  However, most people would not want to go with static addressing, so typically on your average router configuration pages there will be an option that's somewhere in-between: an address reservation table.  There, you assign a **preferred** IP address that's tied to a MAC address (and usually a friendly name field), and DHCP will give that device priority for that address whenever lease

Comment: ...gets renewed.  This way, less chance of something going wrong on the network printer configuration.

Comment: @Arctiic got your point. But the network is completely static already. DHCP is turned off.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I just noticed you added the printer as local port instead of Standard TCP/IP?  Try adding it as TCP/IP as RAW instead?  In some cases, down-versioning over to the PCL5 driver also helps.

Comment: @Arctiic Its just a usb printer connected to a network pc. How can I add that as standard tcp ip port

Comment: This may vary based on the printer make/model, the OS platforms in use, network configuration, etc.  Generally, you can choose to share the printer to network under properties, then choose the driver you want to upload to network, then configure the port.  Under port properties, you can manually choose the type, which you can select as TCP/IP (there's a small wizard you can go through and answer the prompts).  Once it's all done, it should show up as a network device, similar to how SMB shares are accessed.